# How to merge unallocated hard drive space with remaining drive

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I have a 3TB hard drive that has ~700gb of unallocated space not being used. How can I merge this space with the rest of the drive? Do I need to reformat the drive? I cannot delete the unallocated space from disk manager.

[image: disk manager]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [extend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/extend-a-basic-volume) your 2TB partition with the unallocated space. It's quite simple with Windows Disk Manager. You need to be sure that all requierements are met :

> The empty space must be unallocated space that doesn't have a volume on it.
>
> The empty space must be located on the disk drive immediately after the volume that you want to extend.
>
> There can't be any volumes between the volume to extend and the empty space to add.
>
> The volume to extend must be formatted with the NTFS or ReFS file systems.

It will automatically extend your `E:` partition with the new size.

**Caution :** Please make a backup of your data before perform any operation that affects your drive. Even if the operation seems harmless and reliable.

- To be more safe,  @DrMoishe Pippik is right, you need to perform a disk image of your drive, for example you can use CloneZilla for that [here](https://clonezilla.org/downloads.php).

Comment: BTW, from the image, this looks like a simple operation which would have no impact on any data in the existing E: partition, and should complete quickly. That said, before performing *any* major operation on a drive, it is a *very* good idea to make a full disk image, lest something go wrong.

Comment: Yes right, I will edit my answer. Thanks.

Comment: **N.B.** Backing up data is **not** the same as making a disk image. It *might* be just data on drive E:, but a drive may contain recovery, UEFI, boot and other partitions that would not be saved by just backing up data! Make a **disk image**.

Comment: Yes I understand, I'm based on the screenshot it shows. We clearly see that there is only one partition. I will change my answer, no problem.